# Django framework. There was a question concerning creation of the dynamic form on page

Tags: python, django, formset

I am a beginner in django. I am currently writing a test form. There was a question about creating a dynamic form to answer a question. On the page I am creating a question, as well as answers. Questions are created normally, but with the creation of answers, I did not fully understand how to implement it correctly.

views.py

```
def index(request, id):
    question = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    answer = Question.objects.filter(ProfileId_id=question)
    #answer_qs = answer.objects.all()
    question_form_set = inlineformset_factory(Profile, Question, fields=('text_of_question', 'Weight',), extra = 0)
    answer_form_set = inlineformset_factory(Question, Answer, fields=('text_of_answer', 'IsRight',), extra = 0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = question_form_set(request.POST, instance=question)
        formset2 = answer_form_set(request.POST, queryset=answer)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            #formset2.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        formset=question_form_set(instance=question)
        formset2 = answer_form_set(instance=answer)
    form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None, instance=question)
    form2 = AnswerForm(request.POST or None, instance=answer)
    return render(request, 'main/question_ch.html', {'formset': formset, 'form': form,})
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ProfileId = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text_of_question = models.CharField(verbose_name='Текст вопроса', max_length=200)
    Weight = models.FloatField(default=1, verbose_name='Вес')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вопрос'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вопросы'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text_of_question
    

class Answer(models.Model):
    QuestionId = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text_of_answer = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    IsRight = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вариант ответа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Варианты ответа'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text_of_answer
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.